# Javascript audio parallax

Tags: javascript

How to play and pause a audio when changing the game speed in the output. I want to pause the audio when it reaches a 0 value, but above zero, the audio will play.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 500;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 400;

const backgroundLayer1 = new Image();
backgroundLayer1.src = 'layer/layer1.png';
const backgroundLayer2 = new Image();
backgroundLayer2.src = 'layer/layer2.png';
const backgroundLayer3 = new Image();
backgroundLayer3.src = 'layer/layer3.png';
const backgroundLayer4 = new Image();
backgroundLayer4.src = 'layer/layer4.png';
const backgroundLayer5 = new Image();
backgroundLayer5.src = 'layer/layer5.png';
const backgroundLayer6 = new Image();
backgroundLayer6.src = 'layer/layer6.png';

let gameSpeed = 1;
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
slider.value = gameSpeed;
const showGameSpeed = document.getElementById('showGameSpeed');
showGameSpeed.innerHTML = gameSpeed;
slider.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  gameSpeed = e.target.value;
  showGameSpeed.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});

let audio = new Audio('music/sound.mp3'); {
  if (gameSpeed >= 1) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
};


class Layer {
  constructor(image, speedModifier) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 900;
    this.height = 400;
    this.x2 = this.width;
    this.image = image;
    this.speedModifier = speedModifier;
    this.speed = gameSpeed * this.speedModifier;
  }
  update() {
    this.speed = gameSpeed * this.speedModifier;
    if (this.x <= -this.width) {
      this.x = this.width + this.x2 - this.speed;
    }
    if (this.x2 <= -this.width) {
      this.x2 = this.width + this.x - this.speed;
    }
    this.x = Math.floor(this.x - this.speed);
    this.x2 = Math.floor(this.x2 - this.speed);
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x2, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

const layer1 = new Layer(backgroundLayer1, 0.3);
const layer2 = new Layer(backgroundLayer2, 0.1);
const layer3 = new Layer(backgroundLayer3, 0.2);
const layer4 = new Layer(backgroundLayer4, 0.3);
const layer5 = new Layer(backgroundLayer5, 1);
const layer6 = new Layer(backgroundLayer6, 0);


const gameObjects = [layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4, layer5, layer6];

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
  gameObjects.forEach(object => {
    object.update();
    object.draw();
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
animate();
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgreen
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#canvas1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(#3676ec, skyblue, skyblue, skyblue, skyblue);
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; */
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Parallax Backgrounds</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <p>Game speed: <span id="showGameSpeed"></span></p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="5" class="slider" id="slider">
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I set the gameSpeed in the code to 0, the audio pauses, and when I set it to 1, the audio plays; however, if I want to play and pause an audio, moving the slider into zero causes the audio to pause, and moving it above zero causes it to play.

Comment: Have you tried changing `if (gameSpeed >= 1) {` to `if (gameSpeed > 0) {`?

Comment: Yes, the audio will pause but when you move the slider into 1-20 the music is still pause

Answer (score 0):

Move the if-statement (i.e. `if (gameSpeed > 0) etc...`) into your eventlistener.

Also, make sure that `let audio = new Audio('music/sound.mp3');` is before  `slider.addEventListener etc...`. Otherwise `audio` will not be reachable.

Your code should look like this:

```
let audio = new Audio('music/sound.mp3');

slider.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  gameSpeed = e.target.value;
  showGameSpeed.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  
  if (gameSpeed > 0) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
});
```